# ios in-app developer's apps an how to open it without AppStore launching

Tags: app-store, updates

I have already got an app available in App Store, and now making some more. 
I want my new app to contain list of my other apps and to update it automatically when a new app comes out. 
The 2nd I want to make is: on clicking such link I want not to open an AppStore app, but displaying that app info in the app, with ability to install it right from there (an example - Cut the Rope game). 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

In your iTunes store app link you need to change the following text:

```
?ls=1&mt=8
```

to

```
?mt=8
```

This will open the app page as an iTunes preview page.